# .NET Core image that supports both .net core 2.1+ and (node or PowerShell?) in Docker

Tags: node.js, powershell, docker

I'm trying to create a Docker build image in my dockerfile. Since we are using react I will need Node.js on it. As of .Net Core v2.1 this is what I found in ms registry

- microsoft/aspnetcore-build does not support .Net Core 2.1 (but has both PowerShell and Node.js installed)
- microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk is meant for building, but missing both PowerShell and Node.js
- Same goes for microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-nanoserver-1803

I need either node to be preinstalled on the image or PowerShell (so I can download and install Node.js).

Comment: Are you using React as server side render or do you have a single page application?

Answer (score 0):

Use curl instead (body must be at least 30 chars)

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2017/12/19/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/